# Criar um objeto para cada grupo de ids iguais

Tags: jquery

como posso criar um objeto único contendo os dados quando o id pergunta for igual e dentro de um loop $ each ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: no caso quero criar um array para cada id_pergunta exemplo seria o id 63  onde seria um array contendo o id_pergunta a resposta sim e não e suas quantidades. o mesmo deveria acontecer com os demais onde eu teria 4 objetos , um sendo os dados do 63 outro do 64 , mais um do 65 e um do 66, entendeu?

Comment: Coloque o código do array com as várias perguntas assim como a saída esperada, para ser fácil de responder à pergunta